# My AdMob ads don't work, and everything seems to be written correctly

Tags: java, android, admob

My ads do not work and I don't know what is the cause of it. In Activity class, it seems to be everything alright. Same thing is with Gradle. Please help. Maybe something is wrong in AdMob Console.

```
public class RegisterActivity extends BaseActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 9001;

TextView logo;

    private InterstitialAd Memead3;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
        findViewById(R.id.button_sign_in).setOnClickListener(this);
        logo = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        Typeface typeface0 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Baloo-Regular.ttf");
        logo.setTypeface(typeface0);


        Memead3 = new InterstitialAd(this);
        Memead3.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-8090166845540486/4438348515");
        Memead3.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
        MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-8090166845540486~1312841352");

        if (Memead3.isLoaded()) {
            Memead3.show();
        } else {
            Log.d("TAG", "The interstitial wasn't loaded yet.");
        }
```

Gradle:

```
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'

    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:1.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.3.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details. Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help.

Answer (score 1):

From your `onCreate` method:

```
Memead3.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-8090166845540486~1312841352");

if (Memead3.isLoaded()) {
    Memead3.show();
}
```

With this code, you're calling `loadAd`, and then a millisecond or two later trying to show the ad with `isLoaded` and `show`. That's not enough time for the AdMob SDK to download an ad for you, so `isLoaded` will always return false.

I would move your attempt to call `show` out of `onCreate` and into something else, such as a button handler or when the user leaves the activity.

Also, it doesn't look like you're using test ads in this example. You should always use them when developing your app, since testing with live traffic can cause your account to be suspended. See the [Test Ads Guide](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads) for details on how to use them.

Comment: But when I call show out of this method, the method isLoaded gives errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try showing test ads.
Load your ads-integrated app and make an ad request.
Check the logcat output for a message that looks like this:

```
I/Ads: Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("33BE2250B43518CCDA7DE426D04EE232")
to get test ads on this device.
* Copy your test device ID to your clipboard.
* Modify your code to call
```

Then add it to the AdRequest:

```
AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder()
    .addTestDevice("33BE2250B43518CCDA7DE426D04EE232")
    .build();
```

Comment: Or try using admob sample ids - ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712

Answer (score 0):

Call `MobileAds .initialize(...` before trying to load new ads. Also make sure to check logs like "Failed to load ad : 0",etc